# How to change the color of a cell of a table in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my function

```html
<script>
  function colorChange() {
     document.getElementById('change').bgcolor="#00CC99";
  }
</script>
```

and this is my table

```php
 <?php>

 echo("<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\"><tr>\n");
 if($dayArray["month"] == $mydate[month])
 {
   echo ("<td id=\"change\" bgcolor=\"#FF99FF\">
   <a href=\"javascript:colorChange()\"</a>")></td>\n");
  } 
 echo (</table>);
```

but the color of the cell does not change.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

There's no such property as `bgcolor`, there is however an attribute, but you should use element.style :

```
document.getElementById('change').style.background = "#00CC99";
```

or

```
document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundColor = "#00CC99";
```

or if you just have to change the attribute

```
document.getElementById('change').setAttribute('bgcolor', '#00CC99');
```

Comment: @cherouvim - of course, a bit too much copy paste there, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks very messy with `html` embedded inside php `echo` statements. Change this too:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5"><tr>
<?php
if($dayArray["month"] == $mydate[month])
{
?>
 <td id="change" style="background:#FF99FF"><a href="javascript:colorChange()">></a></td>
 <?php
  } 
 ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
//There is no property called 'bgcolor', use style.backgroundColor instead.

function colorChange(){
document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundColor="#00CC99"; bgcolor
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NxmuL/)

Comment: Still some bugs: no closing `<tr>` and `<a>` is broken.